# Find string from responsetext

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

In the responetext is the entire source of the page, but if the page contains a link with the word tuna, how can I grab the link from responsetext?

Comment: is this about *phishing* for tuna ?

Comment: Are you receiving a whole page through ajax, and trying to get a link value by parsing the response ?

Comment: @jad yes I am, and @pavium what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a "fake" div to house your source code in so we can use DOM elements on it, then use `.getElementsByTagName`, simples really!

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = responseText;

var a = div.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
{
   if (a[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf('tuner') != -1)
   {
      alert('i caught da tuna fish. href is: ' + a[i].getAttribute('href'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you can create a new DOM from a string:

```
$(responseText).('a:contains("tuna")').attr('href");
```

Comment: I think you mean: `$(responseText).find('a:contains("tuna")').attr('href');`